# How to loop over associative array using foreach loop construct in following scenairo?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, key-value

I've an array titled `$rebate_by_product`:

```
Array
(
    [op] => preview
    [id] => 
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [company_id] => 46
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 10
            [quantity] => 20
            [volume] => 30
            [units] => 9
            [amount] => 40
            [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-01
            [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-05
            [applicable_states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [rebate_total_count] => 5000
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 10
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 50
            [quantity] => 60
            [volume] => 70
            [units] => 10
            [amount] => 80
            [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-06
            [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-10
            [applicable_states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 15
                    [2] => 16
                )

            [rebate_total_count] => 10000
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 8
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pack] => 100
            [quantity] => 200
            [volume] => 300
            [units] => 7
            [amount] => 400
            [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-21
            [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-30
            [applicable_states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26
                    [1] => 33
                    [2] => 42
                )

            [rebate_total_count] => 9999
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 9
                    [2] => 8
                )

        )

    [multiselect] => 42
)
```

You can observe from above array that it has few elements which are not array but it has three such elements which are themselves array and even few of its data elements are also arrays so how to loop over this kind of array using foreach loop?

Comment: yes we can see that some of the are arrays, some are not, so whats the objective? loop them, and what comes next? please clarify your question and provide the objective and end result

Comment: @kevinabelita:I want to access each of the values and print them using foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print each one the just use foreach loop. Consider this example:

```
$product_keys = array(); // edited
// loop them, if its an array, loop inside it again
foreach($rebate_by_product as $index => $element) {
    if(is_array($element)) {
        foreach($element as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {

                // EDITED
                if($key == 'products') {
                    $product_keys = array_merge($product_keys, $value);
                }

                $value = implode(',', $value);
                echo "$key => $value <br/>";
            } else {
                echo "$key => $value <br/>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$index => $element <br/>";
    }
}

// if product items has duplicates check here (edited)
if(count($product_keys) != count(array_unique($product_keys))) {
    echo "<script>alert('This array has duplicate products');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Products are ok');</script>";
}
```

Or if you want, you cant just use `iterators` on this one:

```
$recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($rebate_by_product));
foreach($recursive as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value <br/>";
}
```

Comment: That would work for the example. If there are more levels, recursion might be a better option.

Comment: yeah, it should work on the example, but it may be good to use iterators on this one. il edit it

Comment: @kevinabelita:Thanks for your answer but I want one more thing the values under products[] should be all defferent irrespective of the inner array (i.e.[1],[2],[3] each of these array should contain different values in their inner [products] array)to which they belong. If match is found echo error message and if not echo success message. Which in all the [product] keys of all the inner arrays repetition of values is not allowed.

Comment: @PHPLover products[] array should contain unique values? like if `array[1]['products']` has `array(1,2,3,3)`, show an error?

Comment: @kevinabelita:yes, it has to show an error. But also I need the different values in other inner array's [product] key. e.g. In above array 9 and 8 is present in third array for third array they are unique but the same 9 and 8 are present in first and second array so in this case also it should echo an error message.Now is everything clear to you. If you still have any doubt you can ask me.

Comment: to check for duplicates you can just put them aside, separate them and put each product inside an array, then check them, use `array_unique` and `count()` if they don't match, then they have duplicates. see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose you're use a recursive approach to bring all the entries of the array on the same level and then print this array:

```
function loopArray($inputVal,$inputKey = "") {
    if(is_array($inputVal)) {
        $output = array();
        foreach($inputVal as $key => $value) {
            $output = array_merge($output,loopArray($value,$key));
        }
        return $output;
    } else {
        return array($inputKey => $inputVal);   
    }
}

// Just for presenting:
$yourArray = array(
    "1" => "1",
    array(
        "2.1" => "2.1",
        array(
            "2.2.1" => "2.2.1"
        )
    ),
    "3" => "3",
    array(
        "4.1" => "4.1"
    )
);

$newArray = loopArray($yourArray);
// > array("1" => 1,"2.1" => "2.1","2.2.1" => "2.2.1","3" => "3","4.1" => "4.1")

foreach($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br/>";   
}
// > 1 => 1
// > 2.1 => 2.1
// > 2.2.1 => 2.2.1
// > 3 => 3
// > 4.1 => 4.1
```